# malloc(): memory corruption; Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, malloc

I'm having a serious problem with malloc() command. The thing is as is: I'm writing a code to perform the calculation of the residual of a matrix linear problem. In order to do so, I'm allocating memory to store a matrix vector `c` which will hold first the result of matrix-vector multiplication. Afterwards I simply substract the resulting vector with another vector, calculate the norm etc...

The error occurs right at allocation after compilation and gives

```
malloc(): memory corruption
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm providing the code here

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../headers/norm.h"
#include "../headers/prodMatVec.h"

double residual(int size, double *a, int *ja, int *ia, double *x, double *b)
/*
  Aim
  ===

      The following functions evaluates the residual of the resolution
      of a linear problem of the form

                           Ax = b

      As the output of the resolution of such a problem is the vector x,
      the residual gives an indication on how far (in terms of the
      the euclidian norm of vectors) lies the product Ax from what it
      should exactly be, namely b. Therefore, the normalized residual is

                           ||Ax - b||
                      r =  ==========
                             ||b||

      This operation involves functions such as matrix-vector product
      and the application of the euclidian norm. These are described
      in the corresponding functions.

  Arguments
  =========
    size  (input)  -  size of the given vectors and matrix
    x     (input)  -  points to table 'x'
    ia    (input)  -  points to table 'ia' from matrix A
    ja    (input)  -  points to table 'ja' from matrix A
    a     (input)  -  points to table 'a' from matrix A
    b     (input)  -  points to table 'b'
*/
{

  /* Variables declaration */
  int i;
  double *c, num, denom;

  /* Memory allocation for temporary result of matrix-vector product */
  c = malloc(size * sizeof(double));  // PROBLEM: MEMORY CORRUPTION
  if (c == NULL) {
    printf("\n ERROR : not enough memory to generate the system\n\n");
    return 1;
  }

  /* Computation of matrix-vector product */
  prodMatVec(size, a, ja, ia, x, c);

  /* Computation of the numerator vector */
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    c[i] -= b[i];

  /* Computation of norms */
  num = norm(size, c);
  denom = norm(size, b);

  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) // not necessary
    c[i] = 1;

  /* Memory release */
  free(c);

  /* Return the quotient between both terms */
  return num/denom;
}
```

Can anyone help me? If needed I can provide more information.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT:

Using `gdb` (which I am not familiar with) the code gives

```
malloc(): memory corruption

Thread 1 "main" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: `The error occurs right at allocation after compilation and gives` means in execution time? Have you tried to use `gdb` to trace the error?

Comment: `valgrind` if you can run this code on a machine that supports it.

Comment: The actual problem might have been caused elsewhere and only shows up when `malloc` gets called.

Comment: This is not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is insufficient information to offer a complete answer.

Comment: The memory is not being corrupted when you call `malloc`. It's getting corrupted later on when you write to the memory. Somehow, you are writing past the end of the memory allocated to your program.

Answer (score 1):

As advised in the comments, an instance of `valgrind` allowed me to find that the problem was lying elsewhere and indeed was due to a writing pas the end of memory allocation.

Thanks to everyone for the help.